# Question on Dedekind's cuts on the Real Line

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading Charles C. Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis, 2nd Ed.On page 17, Pugh shows that $\mathbb R$ has no gaps:

Next, suppose we try the same cut construction in $\mathbb R$ that we did in $\mathbb Q$. Are there gaps in $\mathbb R$ that can be detected by cutting $\mathbb R$ with scissors? The natural definition of a cut in $\mathbb R$ is a division $A\vert B$, where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, nonempty subcollections of $\mathbb R$ with $A \cup B = \mathbb R$, and $a<b$ for all $a∈A$ and $b∈B$. Further, $A$ contains no largest element. Each $b∈B$ is an upper bound for $A$. Therefore $y=\sup A$ exists and $b \geq y \geq a$ for all $a∈A$ and $b∈B$. By trichotomy,

$\displaystyle\qquad A\vert B= \{x∈R:x<y\} \vert \{x∈R:x \geq y\}.$

In other words, $\mathbb R$ has no gaps. Every cut in $\mathbb R$ occurs exactly at a real number.

I can't understand why $y≥a$ is used. I thought $a$ cannot be equal to the least upper bound, since we defined that $a$ has no largest bound in $A$. What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. It should be "$b \ge y >a$".
If $x \ge y$, then $x$ is a upper bound of $A$, and since $A$ has no max, $x>a$ for any $a\in A$, hence $x\in B$. On the other hand, if $x\in B$, then $x$ is an upper bound of $A$, hence $x\ge y$. This shows that $B=\{x| x\ge y\}$.